# Array of plist update data

Tags: iphone, xcode, arrays, sdk, plist

I have this two arrays init with two different plist files, plist files are inside document folder not in the bundle so are editable.

```
progress = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self progressFilePath]];
    easy = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self easyFilePath]];
```

the progress plist is empty insted the easy is:

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>TitleEN</key>
        <string>Hunter</string>
        <key>Status</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>Image</key>
        <string></string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Now in my view I have a tableView loaded with easy and I would like that the element press in the row, if it’s status is 0 it goes to the progress plist, set object for key Image in dog.png in progress.plist also set object 0 for key Status but in the easy one. I did everything with this:

```
NSNumber *status = [[easy objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Status"];
    if ([status intValue] == 0) {

            [progress addObject:[easy objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        int progresstot = [progress count];
        for (int i=0; i<progresstot; i++) {
            if ([[progress objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"TitleEN"] == [[easy objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"TitleEN"]) {
                [[progress objectAtIndex:i] setObject:@"dog.png" forKey:@"Image"];
            }
        }
            [progress writeToFile:[self progressFilePath] atomically:YES];
[[easy objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]        forKey:@"Status"];
             [easy writeToFile:[self easyFilePath] atomically:YES];
      }
```

Everything work fine, but I can’t understand why at the end of this method I have my progress.plist with my element with dog.png but also I have dog.png on the easy one.
(Status is only updated on easy and works good but dog.png on both).
Anyone can help me? I can’t understand what’s wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[progress addObject:[easy objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

You add the object *p1 == [easy objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]* to the progress array, now progress array retained *p1* and has it as one of its elements. It didn't create the new object, it retained the existing one - *p1*.

```
for (int i=0; i<progresstot; i++) {
    if ([[progress objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"TitleEN"] == 
            [[easy objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"TitleEN"]) 
    {
        [[progress objectAtIndex:i] setObject:@"dog.png" forKey:@"Image"];
    }
}
```

- In if-statement you want to compare the objects' content, but not the pointers, I guess.
- Once again, in both arrays you have pointer (*p1*) to the same object, so when you do *[p1 setObject:forKey:];*  -  you do it for both arrays.

Comment: Understood! How can I copy the easy object in the progress array?

Comment: Well, since you're working with classic objective-C object (derived from NSObject), you can just do *NSObject *itemToAdd=[[easy objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] copy]; [progress addObject:itemToAdd]; [itemToAdd release];*     We released itemToAdd, because array will retain it and we don't want to leak *copied* item afterwards

Comment: It doesn't work, shows me this error.
'terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInternalInconsistencyException, reason: -[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
Also I can't release *itemToAdd because I'm using ARC

Comment: Ah, if you're using ARC, then enough just *[progress addObject:[[easy objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] mutableCopy]];*  And yes, since you work with mutable objects, *mutableCopy* must be used